# De que forma iterar en C#?

Tags: c#, bucles

Hola coders tengo una duda con este tema. He observado distintas formas en las que itera un directorio pero pregunto existe una forma en la que este proceso se haga de forma completamente limpia, sin mayo complicaciones o alguna forma predefinida?

Comment: Saludos itsvan, tu pregunta queda como demasiado amplia y/o basada en opiniones dado que en la programación NO existe un solo camino ideal, pues depende del escenario que tengas. Por otro lado, te sugiero realizar la pregunta en META, edita agregando el código que has realizado y una vez que la pregunta tenga forma, publícala nuevamente, mayor calidad en preguntas, mayor calidad en respuestas :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 string lector = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(rutaDelArchivo);
```